# Android displaymetrics to prevent use of xml for different screen sizes

Tags: android, screen-size

I am using xml like layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp. How am I supposed to use display metrics to adjust to the screen size. I am using this below code but unable to adjust to screen size.

```
int dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use values-sw320dp as folder name instead layout-sw320dp. And set your dimension.xml inside that folder based on that values you can change your layout

Please refer this url

https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/res

Comment: What if i want to support all screen sizes including tablets